# Swift Decode JSON Response to GMSCoordinateBounds Array

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

In my app I have the following JSON response and struct which represent the Active working areas

JSON :

```
{
    "status_code": 1000,
    "data": [
        
        {
            "name": "BWME23DW",
            "north_east_lat": 33.34534,
            "north_east_lng": 44.56467
            "south_west_lat": 34.89434,
            "south_west_lng": 44.54567

        },
    ],
    "message": null
}
```

Struct :

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps

struct ActiveBounds : Codable {
    
    var status_code : Int!
    var data : [LatLngBounds]!
    var message : String!
}

struct LatLngBounds : Codable{
    
    var name : String!
    var north_east_lat : CLLocationDegrees!
    var north_east_lng : CLLocationDegrees!
    var south_west_lat : CLLocationDegrees!
    var south_west_lng : CLLocationDegrees!
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        
        case name
        case north_east_lat
        case north_east_lng
        case south_west_lat
        case south_west_lng
    }
    
}
```

after decoding the response i need to check if the user current location is within the Active bounds and this is very easy using `GMSCoordinateBounds.contains(latLong)`
so how i can just decode and initials it directly in my ActiveBounds struct to return the data property as array of GMSCoordinateBounds instead of LatLngBounds struct

This is what Im want to accomplish

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps

struct ActiveBounds : Codable {
    
    var status_code : Int!
    var data : [GMSCoordinateBounds]!
    var message : String!
}
```

Comment: `GMSCoordinateBounds` is to create a rect from 2 coordinates, no? How can it be init with only 1 coordinate? But I'd suggest you create a computed var on `ActiveBounds` that transform an `[LatLngBounds]` into a `[GMSCoordinateBounds]`.

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong code, I update it

Comment: Do you really need it to be inside variable `data`? or can it be another property? Because currently, `GMSCoordinateBounds` needs to be `Codable` too. And if you won't use it, but only in your model...

Comment: I would use a separate model for the GMSCoordinateBounds property instead of changing or extending your json related struct, I think it will be a cleaner solution and easier to modify if you want to add new properties/functionality. Plus, do you really care about that status code and (error?) message once the json has been decoded correctly?

Comment: @Larme its okay to be in another property i just want to access it as array to loop through in my controller to check if the current location is inside one of the active areas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to write `!` at the end of your properties...

The easier way, is do make a lazy var or a computed property on `ActiveBounds` where it will transform `[LatLngBounds]` into a `[GMSCoordinateBounds]`.

```
struct ActiveBounds : Codable {

    var status_code : Int
    var data: [LatLngBounds]
    var message: String

    lazy var coordinatesBounds: [GMSCoordinateBounds] = {
        data.map { GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: $0.north_east_lat, 
                                                                          longitude: $0.north_east_lng),
                                       coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: $0.south_west_lat, 
                                                                          longitude: $0.south_west_lng) }
    }()
}
```

That way, you don't "alterate" your JSON model needing custom `init(from decoder:)`.